# How to share a SQL Server 2008 Standard edition database to another on a computer (wireless network)

Tags: sql-server-2008

Does anyone know how to set the properties of database to be shared through wifi network? I'm running windows 8.1 OS and the other computer I need to share with, is Windows 7. I tried to use 'adhoc' but seems like doesn’t work at all or maybe I used it improperly.

**EDIT:**
I already solved my problem in connecting through other pc using `adhoc`.. Thanks!
but my main problem is **setting properties of a database to be shared**. :-( anyone??

Comment: Are you having trouble sharing the database or connecting the two computers? It seems like you could have more than one problem here...

Comment: uhmm... I think so, but my priority is setting up my database's property to be shared.

Comment: You don't set properties on a SQL database to be shared over a WiFi network. You access a SQL database from other computers using a SQL client.  Do you have a program installed on your other computer that knows how to connect to a SQL database running on another computer? If so, what trouble are you having getting to to connect to the database?

Comment: @twisty A program knows how to connect to SQL database? maybe 'adhoc' .. is it ?

Comment: @DjayPediA Please explain why it seems like it doesn’t work at all. Did you receive any errors? Please provide any error messages that you received.

Comment: @banavalikar I.edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Read about "SQL server surface area configuration" on MSDN for your version of SQL Server. Go here to start: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161956.aspx

In short, you have to do more to share a database over the network even if you can access it locally (server, desktop or laptop where you have install the SQL Server).